# Type constraints in Dafny: Implementing "Show" for a binary relation type

Tags: dafny

I've defined a polymorphic binary relation type (a class) in Dafny:

```
class binRel<S,T>
```

The actual declaration is:

```
class binRel<S(!new,==),T(!new,==)>.
```

I'd like to add a new type constraint: that types S and T should implement a "show" operation (returning a string).

My reading of the Dafny Reference Manual suggests Dafny supports only a few built-in type constraints: ==, and evidently !new, and that there's no way to require that type support, e.g., some particular trait.

Perhaps I'm wrong and that updates more recent than the reference manual have provided such capabilities. Am I in luck? If not, is there perhaps a work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, there are only a few built in type constraints in Dafny. There is no mechanism to require that a type extend a trait.

I'm not aware of a good work around for the object-oriented/imperative fragment of Dafny. In the pure fragment, you could work around this using first-class functions.

```
datatype MyPair<A,B> = MakePair(a: A, b: B)

type Show<!A> = A -> string

function ShowMyPair<A,B>(sa: Show<A>, sb: Show<B>): Show<MyPair<A,B>>
{
  (p: MyPair<A,B>) => "(" + sa(p.a) + "," + sb(p.b) + ")"
}
```